# SQL Server : conversion error numeric to varchar case

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, case

I have this query:

```
CASE ClaimsFees.TBA 
   WHEN 0 THEN CAST(IndemnityReserve AS NUMERIC(9,2)) 
   ELSE 'TBA' 
END AS 'Reserve Indemnity'
```

but I always get this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

I have tried to convert TBA as numeric but I can't do this, I also can't convert all the results to `varchar` because when I transfer to Excel file the number 1.325,27 becomes 132.527,00 with the ##,##0.00 format.

Is there a method in SQL Server that I can use to solve this?

Comment: You certainly can't mix datatypes in a `CASE` statement. Can you use `NULL` instead of 'TBA'?

Comment: Your excel side issue is simply Excel formatting. How are you getting this data into Excel?

Comment: Single quotes designate strings in SQL. Use double quotes around variable names.

Comment: Yep adding null it works But i need to have TBA as result, can i use Replace to change null as tba?

Comment: im using spire.xls  and the method .NumberFormat = "##,##0.00"

Comment: Cast the number back to string inside the `case`. That way, both values in the case will be the same type (string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column can only have one type, and as 'TBA' can only be a string, you'll need to make the numeric a string too.

```
CASE ClaimsFees.TBA WHEN 0 
then cast(cast(IndemnityReserve as NUMERIC(9,2)) as varchar(12))
else 'TBA' 
end as 'Reserve Indemnity',
```

Comment: Yes this works very well in sql i get correct values, but when i pass them on excel whith spire.xls i need to format cells like .NumberFormat = "##,##0.00" and 1325,27 become 132.527,00 but i need 1.325,27, i think now is only a formatting problem but how i can solve?

Comment: @Andrea This is now a different question about how to format numbers in Excel - I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: Right, sorry but im new of stackoverflow

Comment: To be fair, the Excel formatting was part of the original question, and actually forms part of the full problem, even if there is no solution in SQL, so I don't really think it's necessary to start a new question.