# To check whether given input is numeric or character

Tags: sql-server

I want to identify whether the given input is string or numeric and based on that, I want to write the different values(if string then string value and if numeric, then to write numeric value)

I have tried the following code

```
select case when isnumeric('text1') = 1 then
123
else
'abc'
end
```

I got the below error while executing the above query

> cannot convert nvarchar to numeric

.

Comment: A `CASE` expression uses Data Type Precedence to determine the return data type. You have 2 values that could be returned `123`, which is an ìnt`, and `'abc'`which is a `varchar(3)`. As a result, the value `'abc'` will be implicitly converted to an `int` and will fail.

Comment: Also `isnumeric` is a terrible function; it returns false positives negatives. Use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : conversion error numeric to varchar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672358/sql-server-conversion-error-numeric-to-varchar-case)

Comment: Could some one help me on how to overcome this and implement the expected result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any workaround for this.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Where do you want to write? to a table? or on the console? and what is text1. You need to give more details.

Comment: The reason input validation is rarely done at the DB level is this is the wrong place to put this kind of logic. To add, in MS-SQL, I strongly recommend throwing `ISNUMERIC` and any snippet in the waste bin. Put input validation in the front end, if you cannot do that put it at the back end. If you can't, see Se @Caramiriel suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`CAST` It.

Your question is incomplete and not sure what you are going to do but based on error, you can try below

```
SELECT CASE WHEN isnumeric('text1') = 1 THEN CAST(123 AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE 'abc' END
```

Comment: This is not my expected result. I want to write the different values(if string then string value and if numeric, then to write numeric value)

Comment: @Coder That's not possible, `CASE` expression will give you result with single or same datatype. If you want to return multiple items then cast all to `varhcar`